# "The provided app ID does not look like a valid app ID" on Facebook

Tags: facebook, app-id, hootsuite

I am not a coder. I work with Hootsuite and I'm trying to add a new client FB & Instagram. Normally this is very easy. Once I approved Hootsuite access I received this message "The provided app ID does not look like a valid app ID". I followed a few search suggestions now almost ALL of my FB biz pages are showing the same message.  Help!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed a similar situation today when I was happily posting to Twitter and Facebook using Hootsuite. Then, seemingly randomly, FB disconnected from my Hootsuite account and I was unable to reconnect. Then I saw a message from Hootsuite and a follow-on link shown below. I'm guessing my sudden activity alerted FB to my status and revoked my permissions since I am not a steady FB user.

"Facebook is changing the way third-party platforms interact with personal Facebook Profiles. As of August 1, you will no longer be able to publish, schedule, edit, delete, like, comment, or reply to comments for personal Facebook Profiles using Hootsuite."

https://help.hootsuite.com/hc/en-us/articles/360006837814